# Local NuGet package source not showing package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I'm stumped. I've followed the [directions to set up a local NuGet Package Source](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds) as closely as I could, but my package refuses to show up in the NuGet Package manager. The screenshot below shows:

1. I've created the NuGet package
2. I put the package in C:\Packages
3. I created a package source Local that points to C:\Packages
4. In the Package Manager, I've selected Local as the package source

But it cannot find the package.  What am I missing?

[image]

Here's my `.nuspec` for reference, with the assembly name removed.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$AssemblyName%$</id>
    <version>1.2.0-beta2</version>
    <title>$AssemblyName$</title>
    <description>Orders Messages</description>
    <language>en-US</language>
  </metadata>
    <files>
      <file src="bin\Debug\$AssemblyName$.dll" target="lib\net40" />
    </files>
</package>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your NuGet package is a pre-release based on the version since the version in your .nuspec is:

```
1.2.0-beta2
```

So you need to check the Include prerelease check box before your NuGet package will appear in the NuGet Package Manager. Without this checked only stable versions will be displayed.

Comment: wow i never would've thought that's how it determines what is considered to be a prerelease, thanks!